# MongoDB filter out subObject based on a subObject's key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

There is a MongoDB object , with following schema, where keys (key1,key2,key3 can be dynamic so 
querying them manually is not a solution)

```
{
"_id" : <docID>,
"user" : <userID>,
"key1" : {
    "priorityLevel" : "p0",
    "filled" : false,
    "category" : "Basic",
    "fieldType" : "input"
},
"key2" : {
    "priorityLevel" : "p1",
    "filled" : false,
    "category" : "Basic",
    "fieldType" : "input"
},
"key3" : {
    "priorityLevel" : "p0",
    "filled" : false,
    "category" : "Basic",
    "fieldType" : "input"
}
}
```

And now the expected output is to filter out keys where **priorityLevel = p0** and have the output as

```
{
"_id" : <docID>,
"user" : <userID>,
"key1" : {
    "priorityLevel" : "p0",
    "filled" : false,
    "category" : "Basic",
    "fieldType" : "input"
},
"key3" : {
    "priorityLevel" : "p0",
    "filled" : false,
    "category" : "Basic",
    "fieldType" : "input"
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to apply [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) on your `$$ROOT`. Then you need [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) along with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get back to your original shape, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            fields: {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                    cond: { 
                        $or: [ 
                            { $ne: [{ $type: "$$this.v" }, "object" ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$$this.v.priorityLevel", "p0" ] }
                        ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$fields" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fDjpf1m6lTs)